# core.typed - Trying to annotate a Record in dependency

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I'm trying to annotate the Element record in clojure.data.xml which is:

```
(defrecord Element [tag attrs content])
```

I've annotated it as follows:

```
(t/ann-record Element [tag :- t/Keyword  attrs :- (t/HMap :complete? false)
                                    content :- (t/Vec Element)])
```

And I have the following function which doesn't type check:

`(t/ann get-content [Element -> (t/Vec Element)])
 (defn get-content [xml]
   (:content xml))`

with 'Expected: t/Vec clojure.data.xml.Element Actual: t/Any'

I've also tried replacing that with `(get xml :content)` but it fails with the same output.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to fully qualify `Element` in your `ann-record` call (I'm assuming your code is not actually in the `clojure.data.xml` namespace).

The [docs for ann-record](http://clojure.github.io/core.typed/#clojure.core.typed/ann-record) say

```
...
; a record in another namespace
(ann-record another.ns.TheirRecord
              [str :- String,
               vec :- (Vec Number)])
...
```

So in this particular case:

```
(t/ann-record clojure.data.xml.Element
  [tag :- t/Keyword  
   attrs :- (t/HMap :complete? false) 
   content :- (t/Vec Element)])
```